# GET http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: prisma, next.js13, next-auth, supabase, trpc

Yesterday I had to add some changes to my database table and all the data was lost, which it wasn't a problem because I'm just developing the project. The problem arises after I did that. I started to get this 500 server error in development, Im using supabase as a database and Next js app router latest with prisma, trpc and Next auth with google as a provider.

I'm getting this on the main page `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: UNAUTHORIZED`

```
src/trpc/server.ts (61:45) @ from 59 | }) 60 | 
.catch((cause: TRPCErrorResponse) => { > 61 | observer.error(TRPCClientError
.from(cause)); | ^ 62 | }); 63 | }), 64 | ],
```

And I can't access any route. This is the only output I get on the console:

```
<< query #1 user.getInfo { input: undefined, result: 
TRPCClientError: UNAUTHORIZED at TRPCClientError.from 
(webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/TRPCClientError-38f9a32a.mjs:44:16) 
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/trpc/server.ts:63:98)
 { meta: undefined, shape: undefined, data: undefined, [cause]: TRPCError: UNAUTHORIZED 
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server/api/trpc.ts:90:15)
 at callRecursive (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:471:38) 
at resolve (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:501:30) 
at callProcedure (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/config-d5fdbd39.mjs:169:12) 
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/trpc/server.ts:48:91) 
{ code: 'UNAUTHORIZED', [cause]: undefined } }, elapsedMs: 182
```

code in the router server

```
 getInfo: protectedProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    return ctx.db.user.findUniqueOrThrow({
      where: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
    });
  }),
```

I've restarted the database and it doesn't work either. Maybe is a problem in the code but I'm guessing it should let me access the home route at least?

Comment: You haven't provided any code that causes you are getting the error

Comment: I've already solve it thanks to your comment. I had prisma.findUniqueOrThrow({}) and since I've deleted the users I was getting that error continuously.

Answer (score 0):

The code causing the error was this line

```
 getInfo: protectedProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    return ctx.db.user.findUniqueOrThrow({
      where: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
    });
  }),
```

Since I've deleted the database information that line was throwing the error.